# Foreach to retrieve data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve fata from my database using php and mysql.
I've managed to get the data from the first row of the table but I can't seem to find a way for it to get to the second row and so on.

My Database is like this:
(first row from table)

```
id [int] -> 7  
user_id [int] -> 23  
user_task_id [int] -> 4  
description [varchar] -> Text Text Text Text Text  
date_creation [timestamp] -> 2013-07-17  
date_end [datetime] -> 0000-00-00  
date_conclusion [datetime] -> 0000-00-00  
status_id [int] -> 3  
notes [text] -> Text Text Text Text Text Text  
categoria_id [int] -> 12  
entity_id [int] -> 17
```

(second row from table)

```
id [int] -> 8  
user_id [int] -> 6  
user_task_id [int] -> 9  
description [varchar] -> Text Text Text Text Text  
date_creation [timestamp] -> 2013-07-20  
date_end [datetime] -> 0000-00-00  
date_conclusion [datetime] -> 0000-00-00  
status_id [int] -> 4  
notes [text] -> Text Text Text Text Text Text  
categoria_id [int] -> 18  
entity_id [int] -> 10
```

Heres the code:

```
<?php
function get_all_tasks() {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tarefas;";
        $tasks_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($tasks_set);
        return $tasks_set;
}
?>


<table class="table_content">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td>User Task</td>
                            <td>Description</td>
                            <td>Entity ID</td>
                            <td>Date End</td>
                            <td>Status</td>
                            <td>Actions</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php 
                    ?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <?php 
                            if($task_data = mysql_fetch_array(get_all_tasks())){
                            foreach ($task_data as $task) { ?>
                          <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $task['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['user_task_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['description'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['entity_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['date_end'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['status_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "" ?></td>
                          </tr>
                            <?php }}
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: First of all thank you to everyone. I've tryed all the different methods but with no success. I did an print_r to see what's inside the variable i'm working for the expression in the foreach and discovered that the variable only contained the first row. So I think the problem is in the function get_all_tasks(). How can I get all the data from a table and store it in an array to use in the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:

> while ($task = mysql_fetch_array(get_all_tasks()) { your html }

Keep in mind that mysql_* is deprecated it's better to use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php
  function get_all_tasks() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tarefas;";
    $tasks_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($tasks_set);
      foreach ($task_data as $task) { ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $task['id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task['user_task_id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task['description'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task['entity_id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task['date_end'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $task['status_id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "" ?></td>
                      </tr>
                        <?php }

}
 ?>


  <table class="table_content">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td>User Task</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Entity ID</td>
                        <td>Date End</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>Actions</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php 
                ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <?php 
                       echo get_all_tasks() ;
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

note: mysql_* is deprecated it's better to use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

move the call to your function outside of the while loop. and write the code as follows

```
<?php 
   $data = get_all_tasks();
   while (($task = mysql_fetch_array($data))) {
                <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $task['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['user_task_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['description'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['entity_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['date_end'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $task['status_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo ""
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your `get_all_task` function with this:

```
<?php
function get_all_tasks() {
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tarefas;";
        $tasks_set1 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
       while ($task_set = mysql_fetch_array($tasks_set1, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        return $tasks_set;
}
?>
```